# Is it posssible to make pos tagging with wolf (Free Wordnet for French)?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet, pos-tagger, open-multilingual-wordnet

I wonder if it is possible to make pos tagging french text using wolf and nltk like we do it with StanfordPOSTagger? And how do we make it if possible? thanks for your answer

Comment: I would say no. A wordnet is a thesaurus. It can't do POS tagging. You need a POS tagger with a model for tagging french.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now!